# How to open an Android Studio made Flutter project on Mac?

Tags: xcode, macos, flutter, ipa

How can I open an existing Flutter project made by Android Studio on Mac-Os to export ipa version of app? Can it be done with Mac-Os version of Android Studio or I have to do it with X-Code? How?
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I could finally do that by accomplishing the following steps:

- Copy the project into macOs (with X-Code Installed)
- Open it by Android Studio (preferably latest version)
- Enable Flutter and Dart plugin on Android Studio framework settings
- Run command `flutter packages get` (Connection to Flutter repositories must be available)
- Run `flutter build ios --release` as @Günter Zöchbauer truly commented
- Connect iPhone device or simulator and run directly on your device
- If some errors printed you may need to verify your developer account settings on X-Code or check Github page of your libraries for possible iOS issues

Comment: I want to run on Iphone Simulator. Please help

Comment: @user3156040 there is no difference for iPhone device or simulator just follow above instructions

Comment: @MohsenEmami where i should run 'flutter packages get' and 'flutter build ios --release' ??

Comment: @KJEjava48 in your IDE's terminal, you can open it by pressing ALT + F12 keys.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in XCode.
Ensure you run `flutter build ios --release` before you do.

Comment: Is there more detailed information about how to open Flutter project in X-Code and fixing errors and issues?

Comment: I don't think there is much to it. I don't have good Xcode knowledge. What I have seen mentioned and tried myself is opening the Xcode project `flutter create` created in the `ios/` subdirectory.

Comment: I could create and run sample "Counter" Flutter project in Mac but my own project has some issues, It does not recognize .dart libs and files

Answer (score 1):

Connection to physical iPhone device is not necessary. Run any sample project in xcode. Start a Simulator. (Only One simulator preferrably).

1. clone the repository from github into Mac (with X-Code Installed)
2. open terminal.
3. cd to your pubspec.yaml
4. flutter run (it will automatically run flutter pub get)
   (It will launch on the already running iOS simulator)

follow steps on flutter.dev to install flutter. Above steps will only work from terminal if flutter doctor(any flutter command) is recognized